# JavaScript console library

Tags: javascript, android, ios, developer-tools, icenium

I have heard about a JavaScript library that simulates the console from development tools, but I can't find anything on the web.

My need is when I deploy my HTML5 + JavaScript application (with [Icenium](http://www.icenium.com/)) in a device (tablet or smartphone and Android or iOS). Sometimes some bugs only occurs on those devices and not in my desktop's simulator, so a console running on it will be very helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [jqconsole](http://replit.github.io/jq-console/)?

Comment: @BasWildeboer your suggestion was of huge help!! Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: good to hear! Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [jqconsole](https://github.com/replit/jq-console)?

Answer (score 2):

Not JavaScript tools for emulating the console, but here are some other ways around it:

[Chrome for Android has remote debugging through Chrome for Desktop](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging)

And I think Safari has [a similar feature for iOS devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html).

Comment: Nice! I'll take a look it.

Comment: Chrome debugging won't do you any good as Icenium uses cordova, which uses the android webview (not chrome).